# Fool the target app's HWND into thinking mouse moved

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

I am trying to emulate simple mouse movement in a window belonging to another process. My app uses global hooks to inject DLL into the target process (`WH_CBT` and `WH_GETMESSAGE`) and the injection works like a charm. The intention is to fool the target process into thinking the mouse went over a portion of the screen. When I do a movement with the physical mouse, this triggers a certain app behavior (e.g. a tooltip is being shown). I would prefer if the actual mouse pointer remained in its current position when I perform the "trick".

I have established message monitoring with Spy++. Sending (or posting) plain WM_MOUSEMOVE messages to the target HWND is registered by Spy++ but has no desired effect. When the mouse is physically moved, the app does its thing. I have tried sending some other messages in conjunction to WM_MOUSEMOVE (e.g. WM_SETCURSOR) but things didn't improve. I have even hijacked [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the target process to return the same coordinate as posted in WM_MOUSEMOVE (former is screen, latter is client) but this didn't help either.

When I do a simple [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the app does what it's supposed to do. What other magic am I missing that the SetCursorPos is doing? The messages captured by Spy++ look more or less the same in both scenarios.

Any suggestions on how to send mouse movement are welcome. I do not want to use SendInput, mouse_event or other APIs. I need to target a specific HWND for a very brief period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a tooltip is shown as a result of the `WM_NOTIFY` message, which is sent with the `TTN_SHOW` notification code. Have you tried it?

Comment: Hm... Thanks for your attempt but I think you are missing the point. I am trying to accurately simulate a mouse move (just like SetCursorPos does it), not show tooltips.